# How to .join() arrays nicely

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I find `Array.prototype.join()` method very useful when constructing strings from arrays, like

```
"one two three".split(' ').join(', ');
```

But very often I want to generate a string like this:

```
"one, two and three"
```

The method I use is this:

```
var parts = "one two three".split(' ');
parts.slice(0, parts.length-1).join(', ') + ' and ' + parts.slice(-1)
```

This generates what I want, however is an ugly solution I should put into a separate function.

I love one liners and believe there should be more elegant one-liner in JS to accomplish this task. Can someone provide me with one ?

**EDIT**

Please no need to comment that it is a bad practice to write unreadable code. I ask for one! :)
I have learned a lot from one liners about the language constructs and so have a situation where I see a possibility for one. No offense.

**FINAL EDIT**
I appreciate ***Pavlo*** answer as it really shows how easily one liner can become a beautiful readable code. Since I was asking for a one liner so as per my question ***h2ooooooo*** gets the highest score.

Comment: One liners are only good if they're clear as well as concise. I hate code that tries to be too clever and is hard to read. Code should be easy to read to aid maintenance.

Comment: You might be able to get a one liner but it would be extremely unreadable and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I like one liners as they often show advanced usage of language and I like learning new things. it's not the case where I would like to put one liners all over the code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code golf

Comment: Do you care about ever being able to localize your site into languages other than English?  If so, you will need a much more complex function.  The [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) has spent a truly massive amount of time building libraries for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DanielPryden It's not a problem, until it's a problem. We don't know the scope, maybe it's a little side project. No need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: @Pavlo: I mention it because code that tries to format this kind of thing "nicely" becomes an *enormous* pain to deal with if you decide to localize your application, and many times over if the code is written in a tricky manner. It's true, for some projects, you may never have to deal with localization, but that's only because you've (intentionally or unintentionally) decided to exclude the majority of the world's population.

Comment: @DanielPryden Fair enough, but this is not a code review. Localization is definitely out the scope of this question.

Comment: @Pavlo: It's not a code review, it's a request for help solving a problem. I felt compelled to point out that the problem, and the proposed solution space, introduce a limitation into the resulting product. I used a comment on the question to do so. How else would you propose communicating this concern? Remember, StackOverflow questions exist not only to help the questioner, but also to help other random people who find this question through search, for whom concerns like localization might be important. In any case, I've said enough already -- feel free to ignore my comment if you prefer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's still a function, but why not use a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for this?

```
Array.prototype.joinNice = function() {
    return this.slice(0, this.length-1).join(', ') + ' and ' + this.slice(-1);
}

"one two three".split(' ').joinNice();
//one, two and three
```

Comment: Well, I would answer the "why not?" with: It's in general a pretty bad idea to extend native host objects like that.

Comment: @jAndy For what reason? In case the JS standard should add an `Array.joinNice` function?

Comment: Convenience, sanity but foremost its just bad advice in general for the reason you just mentioned. Not just the "standard" may create a similar function, but any other script could possibly do aswell. Basically this comes with the same blood and pain *global variables* do.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am the question author. it was just a funny comment :). And despite it being bad for extending native objects +1 for this as I haven't thought about it

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 And then if a browser does implement it slightly differently, you'll have some interesting surprises/bugs.  Better to override them all, then rename them all with find/replace later on if you want the browser's default.

Comment: Why `slice(0, this.length - 1)` instead of just `slice(0, -1)`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, ...and suddenly all your `for..in` loops break because you forgot to check `arr.hasOwnProperty(i)` within *every loop*.

Comment: @zzzzBov Where exactly do you see any `for..in` loops?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, I'm not talking about the code here, I'm talking about what you'll break when you extend `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Why would extending `Array.prototype` with a non-existing function break `for..in` loops or even have anything to do with it?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, [that's a question for the language designers](http://jsfiddle.net/CmB2g/). You'd have to mark the prototype extension as not enumerable for it to be ignored by `for..in` loops, but doing that isn't backwards compatible, so you'd still be losing out on browser support.

Answer (score 55):

I'm surprised with the amount of cryptic solutions and the fact that nobody used `pop()`:

```js
function splitJoin(source) {
    var array = source.split(' ');
    var lastItem = array.pop();

    if (array.length === 0) return lastItem;

    return array.join(', ') + ' and ' + lastItem;
}

splitJoin('one two three'); // 'one, two and three'
splitJoin('one two');       // 'one and two'
splitJoin('one');           // 'one'
```

Edit: Modified to properly work for any string.

Comment: Despite asking for a one liner - awesome example of readability! Thanks!

Comment: +1 for clean solution, -1 for unexpected side effect.

Comment: @BoppreH, what is the unexpected side effect?

Comment: @Frank The unexpected side effect is removing the last element of the list you asked to join.

Comment: @BoppreH Which doesn't really matter as we create that array inside the function any way - why care if we pop the last element?

Comment: @h2ooooooo You are right, I can't believe I missed. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised no one has pointed out that most of these answers won't work properly with zero or one elements in the array. Here's a simple solution that will work fine for 0+ elements:

```
function prettyJoin(array) {
    return array.length > 1
           ? array.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " and " + array.slice(-1)
           : array + "";
}

prettyJoin([]);                          // ""
prettyJoin("one".split(" "));            // "one"
prettyJoin("one two".split(" "));        // "one and two"
prettyJoin("one two three".split(" "));  // "one, two and three"
```

Comment: Why not check if array has less than two elements in a first place?

Comment: You could do that too, e.g. return array + ""; in that case. It's really just a matter of taste.

Comment: No, it's a matter of readability and performance: you don't have to do those slices and joins if you know the result beforehand.

Comment: Performance-wise, it really shouldn't be very significant, since the slice/join calls do basically nothing. Point taken on readability, though - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
(parts = "one two three".split(" ")).slice(0, parts.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + parts.slice(-1);
```

Comment: This would never pass a code review... It gets the job done, but at what price to the sanity of the programmer who needs to maintain it?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis only because you know what it is supposed to do, come back after you have forgotten that little fact and need to reconstruct why it was written like that

Comment: @ratchetfreak you've got a good point. Now it has been only 3 hours since and it's hardcore!

Comment: +1, pretty readable for me too; still would prefer to functionize this. BTW, `parts.length - 1` may be replaced with just `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
"one two three".split(' ').join(', ').replace(/^(.+),/, "$1, and")
```

(It even more grammatically correct!)
Though it won't work as expected if last part itself contains a comma.

Comment: Change `$1,` to `$1`. It will output `one, two, and three` instead of  `one, two and three`

Comment: @thefourtheye, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Its not about English. Please check the expected output in the question again.

Comment: @thefourtheye, it is deliberate change, which can be easily understood from accompanying text. I also believe that it stupid simple for anyone who want it without comma to change it themselves without me holding their hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one liner

```
"one, two and three"
```

---

A bit more generic..

```
function splitJoin (str,del,arr) {
    for (x=str.split (del),i=x.length;i--;x[i]+=(arr[i]||"")); return x.join("");
}

console.log (
    splitJoin ("one two three"," ", [", "," and "])
) //one, two and three
```

Comment: @blesh Totally correct, changed it, the traditional way is shorter anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's pretty though. Or supported in all browsers.

```
parts.reduce(function(val1, val2, i, arr) {return val1 + (i + 1 < arr.length ? ', ' : ' and ') + val2});
```